Django CustomUser Model Causes Lazy Reference Errors During Migration
I have defined a CustomUser model in a Django app called authentication. I've correctly set the AUTH_USER_MODEL to reference this model, but when I try to run migrations, I get the following errors:
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'authentication.customuser', but app 'authentication' doesn't provide model 'customuser'.  
The field authentication.Device.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'authentication.customuser', but app 'authentication' doesn't provide model 'customuser'.       
The field authentication.MoodReview.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'authentication.customuser', but app 'authentication' doesn't provide model 'customuser'.   
The field authentication.PasswordResetCode.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'authentication.customuser', but app 'authentication' doesn't provide model 'customuser'.
The field authtoken.Token.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'authentication.customuser', but app 'authentication' doesn't provide model 'customuser'.

# authentication/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The Email field must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # ... other fields
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


Updated configuration
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.CustomUser'

INSTALLED_APPS:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'authentication',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    # ... other apps
]

